# Tkinter don't display line chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, tkinter

in the calc def I want to display all of the for cycle (picture by picture)  on the gui with the draw def, but only the last one is showed. I tried it 2 different way but none of them worked. I guess the problem is that I give them 1 place and all of them is showed on that place in the top of each other. How can I solve that? Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends._backend_tk import NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from pandas import DataFrame
from decimal import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x300')
root.title('PythonExamples.org - Tkinter Example')

global e1
global numm
global my_entry
my_entry= Entry(root)
e1=Entry(root)
e1.place(x=100,y=180)
korok=Entry(root)
korok.place(x=100,y=210)
entries=[]
entries2=[]
new_array=[]


def calc(numbers):
    n=int(korok.get())
    P=np.dot(numbers,numbers)
    for i in range(n):
        P=np.dot(P,numbers)
        draw(P)
        np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
        print(P)

    label = Label(root, text=str(P),font=("Arial", 15)).place(x=20, y=60)

def draw(data):
    fig,a = plt.subplots()
    df2 = DataFrame(data)
    figure2 = plt.Figure(figsize=(5, 5), dpi=50)
    ax2 = figure2.add_subplot(111)
    line3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure2, root)
    line3.get_tk_widget().place(x=300,y=100)
    #line3.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5, column=5)
    df2.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax2, fontsize=10)
    plt.close(fig)
    ax2.set_title('Markov')
def create():
    numm = int(e1.get())
    global my_entry
    for x in range(numm):
        row = []
        for i in range(numm):
            my_entry = Entry(root)
            my_entry.grid(row=x, column=i)
            row.append(my_entry)
        entries.append(row)


def save():
    my_array = [[float(el.get()) for el in row] for row in entries]
    new_array = np.asarray(my_array)

    calc(new_array)


create = Button(root,text='Submit',command=create).place(x=40,y=180)
save = Button(root,text='Szamol',command=save).place(x=40,y=210)

my_label=Label(root,text='')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand is the concept of `figure` and `axes` in `matplotlib`

**Figure** is like a sheet, you can draw many things on it
`plt.subplots` function creates spaces where you can draw on a figure.

**Axes** is where you can show your data with X and Y

Main error : on `draw` function, you create a new figure every time, that is  every figure is drawn on top of each other. Create figure once (in `calc`) then draw on different axes with `draw` function.

Here is some corrections I made, suit them in your program

```py
def calc(numbers):
    n=int(korok.get())
    P=np.dot(numbers,numbers)
    fig, a = plt.subplots(n, 1) # Create n row of 1 plot in fig
    for i in range(n):
        P=np.dot(P,numbers)
        draw(P, fig, a[i]) # specify which axis where show P
        np.set_printoptions(precision=3)
        print(P)
```

Here, you can use `plt.subplots(n_rows, n_columns)` function where `n_rows` is the number of rows `n_columns` of columns.

A lot more changes in `draw`

```py
def draw(data, figure, ax):
    df2 = DataFrame(data)
    line3 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, root)
    line3.get_tk_widget().place(x=300,y=100)
    #line3.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5, column=5)
    df2.plot(kind='line', legend=True, ax=ax, fontsize=10) # ploting on ax axis space
    plt.close(figure)
    ax.set_title('Markov') # Specify the title of ax axis
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it start to make sense but the I got one more question. I want to plot the charts from left to right(so X axis I guess)  not from the top to bottom (Y axis I guess), how can I make that ?

Comment: Edited, in your case just replace actual subplot by `plt.subplots(1, n)`